# How to make a web server page refresh often?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webserver, esp32

I am developing a web server using an ESP32.

[image: Web server]

My web server just refreshes when I press the buttons. How do I make it refreshes automatically?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A web server does not refresh a page, it serves content that the client requested for. If the client asked for a whole page, it will serve the content of the whole page, if you want the client only to update a portion of the page, then you need to ask for a data (not a whole page) and it is client's responsible to get the response data from the server and insert it to update part of the page. All done at the client side, not on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

one solution I could think of in HTML is using a **meta tag**.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
</head>
```

This will auto-reload the page every 10s, if you don't want this behaviour, another solution is using setInterval.

---

The **setInterval()** method calls a function at specified intervals (in milliseconds)
[learn setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

```js
 let count = 10;
const element = document.getElementById("demo");

setInterval(function() {
  count+=1;
  element.innerHTML = count;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

count: 
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `count+=1` should be just `count++`. Beside that, it will do the user-sided and not server sided by the web-server. The question itself misses details and clarity about what the OP actually tries to achieve.

Comment: When I use this code every time the web server auto-reload, it also activate the buttons. How can I solve it?